# Validations in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am using, "formsy-react" module for validations, where I need to create different class for input type="text", type="checkbox", type="radio"
Is there any better way to achieve validations in react.
Please let me know module name and features.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what your question is. `formsy-react` allows validation to be passed as a prop. Are you wanting to change the CSS class for various input types based on some kind of validation?

Answer (score 0):

A "better way" is subjective. It depends on your use case.

The simplest way to validate input data is using the HTML attribute *pattern* which you can read about [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145)

For example, to only allow maximum 3 lowercase and uppercase letters without any special characters or numbers:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" />
```

Another way of validating data is by using Regex (which is automatically generated with the pattern attribute stated above). But you can do it manually.

Javascript example for validating an e-mail address:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
```

}